# Script created in Spyder but not found in normal folder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I've donwloaded Spyder IDE(inside Anaconda) in order to do a data science 101 course and started to create some simple scripts[image: Some random scripts]

the cwd is C://python/ and in normal folder, they aren't showed[image: it says the folder is empty]

As you can see, in spyder explorer view, the script exist, but with CMD or normal folder browser, it does not see anything, like they were never created(but they exist somehow).
Checked rights and users in windows, but I'm the admin, so there should be no problem.
***Why I can't see my scripts in normal folder?*** 
OS : win 8 with Python 3.7, Anaconda Navigator 1.9.2 Spyder 3.3.1

Comment: Maybe the files are hidden for some reason - can you select 'Show hidden files...' in Folder Options?

Comment: Thank you @Stuart, but the problem was not with "Show hidden files". The problem was that setting Comodo Internet Security with stealth mode, SandBox was auto enabled and so the files were created "virtually".
I realized that if you disable Sandbox feature in Comodo Internet Security, the problem is gone.